# Hashmap.containsKey with array as key doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        var map= HashMap<IntArray, Boolean> ()
        map.put(intArrayOf(1,2,3,4),true)
        map.put(intArrayOf(2),true)
        map.put(intArrayOf(3),false)
        if (map.containsKey(intArrayOf(3))) println("hello, i'm here")

}
```

I have some line of code in kotlin.
it's seem like i need to modifie the comparator of method containsKey(). Can some one show me how. Thank you

Comment: This is expected. How about a `HashMap<List<Int>, Boolean>`?

Comment: yeah, it work, but i have to convert so many array. Is it make my code slow?

Comment: [Race your own horses please.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: By the way, what platform are you on? Kotlin/JVM?

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin arrays do not override `equals` or `hashCode` (which is what `HashMap` uses), Therefore, the implementation from `Any` is inherited, and `equals` compares reference equality.

Alternatives I can think of:

- [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with a custom comparer

  ```
    TreeMap<IntArray, Boolean>(Arrays::compare)
  ```

  Unlike `equals`, [`Arrays.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#compare(int%5B%5D,int%5B%5D)) actually compares the contents of the array, and we are using that as the comparer for the `TreeMap`, which is a map implementation that allows us to specify a custom comparer. Do note that  this has worse asymptotic performance (logarithmic vs constant time) compared to `HashMap`, and that it is JVM-only.

  You should also make sure not to modify the arrays once they are put inside the map, as this can lead to unspecified behaviour.
- `HashMap<List<Int>, Boolean>`

  Change the keys to lists, which do override `equals` and `hashCode`. This has the additional advantage of making the keys immutable, so you won't accidentally change the keys once they are in the map and cause unspecified things to happen.